# S.T $(\forall\epsilon>0)(\forall n\in\mathbb{N}) :n \geq N \implies \left|x_{n}-x\right| \leq ε.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-writing

$(a)$ Suppose that $\left(x_{n}\right)_{n}$ is a sequence and there exists $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\exists \epsilon>0$ and $\exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geqslant N$
implies
$$
\left|x_{n}-x\right| \leqslant \varepsilon
$$
$(b)$ If possible, give an example of a divergent sequence and an $x$ which nevertheless satisfies the condition
above.

---

$(a)$ I've not been able to come up with a formal proof since the limits in convergence theorem usually uses this condition for proving. This requires that we be able to prove that $$
\left|x_{n}-x\right| \leqslant \varepsilon
$$ and I'm clueless on how to proceed with that.

$(b)$ Here, I figured $(−1^n)_n$; $x = 0$ and $\epsilon = 2$ should work but that's oscillating and not divergent. I can't think of another example that would satisfy this condition.

Edits: Corrected a mistake pointed out by Fred

Comment: First $∃ε>0$ and then $\forall \epsilon>0$ ???

Comment: Sorry, that was a LaTeXing mistake. I've corrected it.

Comment: You want a sequence that satisfies the convergence criterion and yet is divergent? Because that's what your question is implying, if I understand it correctly.

Comment: @tmaj Yeah, it seems wrong. The sequence I gave above was the only example given but I realised it's oscillating (not divergent).

Comment: @user220704 an oscillating sequence fails to satisfy the criterion *for every* $\varepsilon > 0$ and is therefore divergent.